# strange pymongo behaviour when adding python list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i have this code:

```
for product_code in product_codes:
    product_categories = []
    product_belongs_to = []
    get_categories = """SELECT * FROM stock_groups_styles_map WHERE stock_groups_styles_map.style ='%s'""" % (product_code,)
    for category in sql_query(get_categories):

        if {product_code: category[1]} in product_categories:
            pass
        else:
            product_categories.append({product_code: category[1]})

    for category in product_categories:
        category_group = get_group(category.values()[0])
        if category_group:
            category_name = category_group.replace("-", " ").title()
            if category_name:
                if category_name == "Vests":
                    product_belongs_to.append(get_category_ids("Tanks"))
                else:
                    cat_value = get_category_ids(category_name)
                    if cat_value:
                        cat_id = get_category_ids(category_name)
                        product_belongs_to.append(cat_id[0])


ccc_products = {
    '_id': ObjectId(),
    'collectionId': collectionId,
    'categoryIds': product_belongs_to,
    'visible' : 'true',
    }
products.save(ccc_products)
```

when i look at the mongdb collection, i have:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53aaa4e1d901f2430f25a6ba"),
    "collectionId" : ObjectId("53aaa4d6d901f2430f25a604"),
    "visible" : "true",
    "categoryIds" : [
        ObjectId("53aaa4d6d901f2430f25a5fc"),
        ObjectId("53aaa4d3d901f2430f25a5f9")
    ]
}
```

this is correct, but if i only have one item in the `product_belongs_to` list, i get:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53aaa4e1d901f2430f25a6bd"),
    "collectionId" : ObjectId("53aaa4d6d901f2430f25a604"),
    "visible" : "true",
    "categoryIds" : [
        [
            ObjectId("53aaa4d6d901f2430f25a5fe")
        ]
    ]

}
```

basically, `"categoryIds"` is an `array` containing an `array`

the only way to fix this is to do the following:

```
if len(product_belongs_to) == 1:
    product_belongs_to = product_belongs_to[0]
```

what am i missing?

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this line is the problematic one:

```
product_belongs_to.append(get_category_ids("Tanks"))
```

`get_category_ids` is returning a list which you're appending to `product_belongs_to`.

You probably wanted to merge the results instead, so that they contain unique values:

```
product_belongs_to = list(set(product_belongs_to + get_category_ids("Tanks")))
```

Comment: @khinester it's always useful to accept the answer if it helped :)